# Remove Text Padding/Margin inside VML Shape

Tags: html-email, padding, vml

I'm trying to figure out how to get this text (!) to show up. Even though it's smaller than the circle it's in, it still gets cut off about 1/3 of the way in to the circle.

I would like to use this for Outlook specifically.

```
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:20px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:20px;" arcsize="50%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ffcb05">
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">!</center>
</v:roundrect>
```

[image: Overflow issue]

Anyone have any ideas? I've tried `overflow:visible` on the circle to no avail.

**More information**

Using a macro to get test html into Outlook.

It is most definitely some sort of margin or padding on the `v:roundrect` element. After importing the HTML, I can right click, go to Format Shape, then Layout & Properties, which gives me the 4 "margin" options. Setting them to zero gives me the desired effect. The issue is that I cannot then grab this HTML, and I have no idea what property this is correlating to.

Latest code:

```
<v:roundrect style="height:30px;width:30px;margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important; mso-margin-bottom-alt:0 !important;mso-margin-top-alt:0 !important;mso-margin-right-alt:0 !important;mso-margin-left-alt:0 !important;mso-padding-bottom-alt:0 !important;mso-padding-top-alt:0 !important;mso-padding-right-alt:0 !important;mso-padding-left-alt:0 !important;" arcsize="50%" strokeweight="2px" strokecolor="#FFFFFF" fillcolor="#ffcb05" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important;mso-margin-bottom-alt:0 !important;mso-margin-top-alt:0 !important;mso-margin-right-alt:0 !important;mso-margin-left-alt:0 !important;mso-padding-bottom-alt:0 !important;mso-padding-top-alt:0 !important;mso-padding-right-alt:0 !important;mso-padding-left-alt:0 !important;">!</center>
</v:roundrect>
```

I've attempted using different elements (span, p, etc..) instead of center.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Textbox with zeroed inset is the key. I had tried it before, but without nested html. Text directly input in the `v:textbox` element does not appear to work, so I used a `center` element to encapsulate text and set styles.

```
<v:roundrect style="height:20px;width:20px;" arcsize="50%" strokeweight="2px" strokecolor="#FFFFFF" fillcolor="#ffcb05" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
        <center style="font:300 14px/15px Impact, Sans-serif;color:#FFFFFF;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">!</center>
    </v:textbox>
</v:roundrect>
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to solve your problem: https://buttons.cm/

Comment: These buttons have the same issue. If there's not enough room around the text it gets clipped in outlook.

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty because in a roundabout way this helped me come to my conclusion, and I can't give myself the bounty.

Comment: Thank you very much :) and I'm happy that you could solve it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding line-height: 16px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; to the center style attributes. Outlook, particularly later versions, tends to tack on a lot of extra spacing above and below text, and won't follow your line height unless you force it.

Comment: No effect, sadly. But there's definitely some extra room above it. I've tried margin and padding zero everything too.